AngleSharp returns nothing with QuerySelectorAll
I am trying to scrape press releases from a website using c# .net 8 with AngleSharp library. Here's the anchor tags am trying to get.
<a class="search-result ng-scope" ng-repeat="result in sc.searchResults" style="margin: 15px 0px 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);" href="https://www.xxxxxxx.ie/News/report-projects-600">
  <span style="text-transform:capitalize;color:#006784;font-weight:700;" class="ng-binding">press releases&nbsp; &nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
  <span style="text-transform:capitalize;color: #36424a;" class="ng-binding">Friday 8 Mar 2024</span>
  <h3 class="ng-binding">report projects 600</h3>
</a>

<a ng-href="https://www.xxxxxx.ie/News/council-nominations" class="search-result ng-scope" ng-repeat="result in sc.searchResults" style="margin:15px 0 0 0;background: #FFFFFF;" href="https://www.xxxxxxx.ie/News/council-nominations">
  <span style="text-transform:capitalize;color:#006784;font-weight:700;" class="ng-binding">press releases&nbsp; &nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
  <span style="text-transform:capitalize;color: #36424a;" class="ng-binding">Friday 8 Mar 2024</span>
  <h3 class="ng-binding">Council Nominations</h3>
</a>

And here's the c# code am using
var config = AngleSharp.Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
var document = await context.OpenAsync("https://www.xxxxxxx.ie/News/NewsFilter/search?resource=339&resources=200");

var elements = document.QuerySelectorAll(".search-result");
if (elements != null)
{
    // Extract the data you need 
}

The issue is, the variable elements.Length is always zero. What might I be doing wrong? Thanks.

Isn't it possible that you are searching for the elements before they are created?

Not likely, the elements are not dynamically created.
